# Speed up sending messages

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an azure function that sends around 20k messages to a service bus. First i started out with doing await operation but realized that was far to slow. Following I tried without the await and that speeded it up. However I cant just return from my azyre function before all messages are send as this would terminate the process. I then tried following:

```
     string queuePath = "xx";
     var queueClient = new QueueClient(_serviceBusConnectionString, queuePath);

     foreach(var tenantSite in tenatSites)
     {
        var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tenantSite);

        string messageBody = jsonStr;
        var message = new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
        var task = queueClient.SendAsync(message);
        tasks.Add(task);
     }
     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

The problem here is it seems to wait for all messages being proccessed instead of just delivered. What is the right approach for sending a high amount of messages to a service bus, and wait for all delivered (not proccessed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at what Bindings can do for you. And in your case specifically: [Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus).
And to be even more specific: using `ICollector<T>` or `IAsyncCollector<T>` is there for creating multiple messages. A message is created when you call the Add method.

An example implementation would look something like this:

```
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
public static void Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "some-route")] HttpRequest req,
    [ServiceBus("some-queue-name", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionSend", EntityType = EntityType.Queue)] ICollector<string> queueCollector,
    string name, ILogger log)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(tenantSites, (tenantSite) =>
    {
        var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tenantSite);

        queueCollector.Add(tenantSite);
    });
}
```

Comment: Ohh havent thought about server side. So what your saying is having one instance of the function, spawning more threads? Will that increase the speed sending the messages from the client? Another thing it is very important that I always only have 10 instances running at the time. With a separate instance for each function I control that with {
  "serviceBus": {
    "maxConcurrentCalls": 10,
    "autoRenewTimeout": "00:00:00"
  }
} can you do that with your approach?

Comment: I don't entirely get your statements, since the code above is (partially) the code from an actual Azure Function I created for a talk on Serverless. It enables you to send multiple messages to a ServiceBus queue without having to manage connections yourself. The `ICollector<string>` is a simple solution to add multiple messages to a queue quickly.  You should be able to use the `ServiceBus` binding and the code in the `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Ahh got it. Your actually a little ahead because right now I have a simple windows client that add the messages to a queue, and it is that client thats is slow adding the messages. Next step was to convert it to a azure function and then I can use your suggestion. Thanks alot.